# Test for day or night: Insert data from API into NSDate object with desired format

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to test for day or night by comparing an observationTime to a sunsetTime, both pulled from underground.

I've pulled the JSON data from the API into a weatherDictionary.

I can pull the observationTime directly, and compare that to current time to get a timeSinceObservation (not related to question).

Now I need to test for day / night. The API allows me to pull sunset time in two strings: sunsetHour and sunsetMinute, initialized as NSStrings.

I need to take those two NSString objects, stick them together, then subtract that from timeNow to test for day / night.  I've stuck sunsetHour and sunsetMinute together to form sunsetTime, but I need to add the other pieces of the dateFormat, and can't figure out how to do it without creating another dateFormatter, which is ungainly.

I feel there must be a more elegant way to accomplish this. Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Here's the deal:

```
//time since observation - cache this date formatter later

NSString *observationTime = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"observation_time_rfc822"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *timeNow = [NSDate date];
NSDate *timeObserved = [dateFormatter dateFromString:observationTime];
int difference = [timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:timeObserved] / 60;
self.timeSinceObservation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i minutes ago", difference];

//sunset

NSString *sunsetHour = [[[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"sun_phase"] valueForKey:@"sunset"] valueForKey:@"hour"];
NSString *sunsetMinute = [[[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"sun_phase"] valueForKey:@"sunset"] valueForKey:@"minute"];
NSString *sunsetTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", sunsetHour, sunsetMinute];

//now change sunsetTime into an NSDate...
```

Comment: Hint:  (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) = seconds.  You can do arithmetic on NSDate objects using NSTimeInterval values which are actually just `double` values expressed in seconds.  (Or you could use NSDateComponents and do the same arithmetic somewhat more tediously.)

Comment: Very good information regarding the duplicate answer - however, the duplicate alone didn't quite do it, although it pointed me in the correct direction. I've edited the post to show the altered code after consulting related answers then digging into the documentation. I would not have found the documentation I needed without the answers on SO.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the body of your question. It's acceptable to post an answer to your own question below, in the answer space, but I don't see it being necessary in this case; the important part of your solution code is exactly the same as the code from the duplicate. The rest is stuff that's too particular to your situation to matter for a future searcher.

Comment: For your last sentence, yes, ivars are initialized to 0, including `BOOL`s, but there's a better way to do that `if` statement anyways: `self.isNight = sunsetDifference <= 0; NSLog(@"is it night time? %hhd", self.isNight);` The result of a comparison expression is a boolean, and it can be assigned to a variable.

Comment: If you need this information in order to change the theme, there is a much better solution (pioneered by Tapbots): Read the brightness of the screen and compare it with a threshold set by the user. If the brightness is higher than the threshold, it's day. Otherwise it's night.

Comment: @dasdom thanks that's a great suggestion and I'll remember it! In my situation I change the theme based on official sunset, pulled from an API. The trouble was formatting the data returned from the API in a usable way. As always.